# Flutter apk is not able to create local text file on physical device

Tags: flutter, apk

I generated a signed APK file for my Flutter app. In this app, a local text file is created and updated. The app is running fine on emulator without any additional permission. But, when apk is installed on my mobile, there is no data related to the created local text file. The installed app is not able to create the text file.
I also checked the app permissions on the mobile, but the options to give storage permission is disabled for the app.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add this line to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```